# May one hold together a tallis with materials that cannot themselves form a tallis?

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

Can someone use material to hold together a tallis (e.g safety pin etc.) that cannot itself make a kosher tallis?

Comment: What is a "kosher tallis"? Do you mean material that can be used to make kosher _tzitzit_?

Comment: kosher tallis, i.e material that requires tzitzis. For instance, leather doesn't ever need tzitzis.

Comment: you ask the din if we coat the wool with a leather patch?

Comment: @kouty a minority, i.e use something like a safety pin to hold pieces together

Comment: So, the ptilim are here for the wool; the fact that the wool is reinforced with leather do not influence the din.

Comment: are you asking about something like a tallis clip which helps keep the tallis on or something used in the actual construction on the tallis itself?

Comment: @Dude, actual construction, like instead of actually sewing a torn tallis, use a bobby-pin to keep part of it attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mechaber writes](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.10.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)  that clothing whose corners are leather (a material not Mechuyav in Tzitzis) while the rest is from cloth, is Mechuyav in Tzitzis, and the opposite is Patur.

The [Maggen Avraham](http://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.10.5?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) writes that this is because we look at the majority of the cloth's makeup.

This Halachah is based on the Mishnah in Kla'im, which says that regarding Shatnez we judge a cloth by its majority. (I recall seeing this Mishna mentioned in the MA but can't find it now.)

Comment: Where does the ma say that?